# How can I open a File Explorer window from a Visual Studio app and set the position and size?

Tags: vb.net, resize, explorer

I have a VB.net application that compacts JPG files, renames them, and copies them from one location to another.  When the end-user uses the program, they'll open two file explorer windows to get the source and destination locations and drag them onto the text boxes.

I have added code that opens two file explorers to set locations, but I would like one windows to be in the lower left size of the screen and the other to be in the lower right.  Each would be sized to take up 1/4 of the screen.

Most of what I have found is very old.  I've found people who said it can't be done and others who provide very old code that doesn't seem to play nice with Visual Studio 2019.

```
Private Sub btnOpenExplorer_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnOpenExplorer.Click

    Process.Start("explorer.exe", String.Format("/n, /e, {0}", "C:\Users\" & Environment.UserName & "\Box\Site Visit Photos"))
    Process.Start("explorer.exe", String.Format("/n, /e, {0}", "P:\"))

End Sub
```

The above code works well.  I just need to add sizing and positioning.

Comment: Create your own file explorer windows in code, Follow [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/creating-an-explorer-style-interface-with-the-listview-and-treeview?redirectedfrom=MSDN), c# but the idea is the same

Comment: This can be easily done with UI Automation (to detect/catch the Explorer's Windows when you open them) and [SetWindowPos](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowpos) (to position/size the Windows). But, could you use a (standard) FolderBrowser Dialog instead of dragging a Folder from two different Explorer Windows?

Comment: @Jimi and djv The end user uses the explorer Windows to get their locations and then they start the process.  They then use the explorer windows to find the next location while the process continues to run.  It's just easier to keep them outside the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution 1

**The Problem**

I think it's difficult to do it in the caller routine `btnOpenExplorer_Click` since it will be too early to get a process object with all of its properties assigned. Mostly, the [ProcessMainWindowTitle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.mainwindowtitle?view=netframework-4.8) and the [Process.MainWindowHandle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.mainwindowhandle?view=netframework-4.8) properties which are needed to solve this problem. A workaround to do this is to make the caller starts the processes and a Timer to do the positioning and resizing by the [SetWindowPos](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowpos) function.

Here's how I'd do it:

**The API Functions**

```vb
<DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint:="SetWindowPos")>
Private Shared Function SetWindowPos(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal hWndInsertAfter As IntPtr, ByVal X As Integer, ByVal Y As Integer, ByVal cx As Integer, ByVal cy As Integer, ByVal uFlags As UInteger) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)> Boolean
End Function

<DllImport("user32.dll")>
Private Shared Function IsIconic(hWnd As IntPtr) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)> Boolean
End Function

<DllImport("user32.dll")>
Public Shared Function ShowWindow(hWnd As IntPtr, <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)> nCmdShow As Integer) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)> Boolean
End Function
```

**Class Level Constants & Variables**

```
Private Const HWND_TOP As Integer = &H0
Private Const SW_SHOWNORMAL As Integer = &H1

Private dir1, dir2 As String
Private WithEvents Timer1 As New Timer With {.Interval = 250}
```

**Process Finder**

```vb
Private Function GetExplorerProcess(title As String) As Process
    Dim dirName As String = If(IO.Directory.Exists(title), New IO.DirectoryInfo(title).Name, title).ToLower

    Return Process.GetProcesses.Where(
        Function(a) a.ProcessName.ToLower.Equals("explorer") AndAlso
        a.MainWindowTitle.ToLower.Equals(dirName)
        ).FirstOrDefault
End Function
```

**The Caller**

```vb
Private Sub btnOpenExplorer_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnOpenExplorer.Click
    Dim proc1 As Process = GetExplorerProcess(dir1)

    If proc1 Is Nothing Then
        Dim procInfo1 As New ProcessStartInfo With {
        .FileName = "explorer.exe",
        .Arguments = dir1,
        .WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal
        }

        Process.Start(procInfo1)
    End If

    Dim proc2 As Process = GetExplorerProcess(dir2)

    If proc2 Is Nothing Then
        Dim procInfo2 As New ProcessStartInfo With {
        .FileName = "explorer.exe",
        .Arguments = dir2,
        .WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal
        }

        Process.Start(procInfo2)
    End If

    Timer1.Start()
End Sub
```

**The Timer - Activate the Windows, Set Both Size & Location**

```vb
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Dim proc1 As Process = GetExplorerProcess(dir1)
    Dim proc2 As Process = GetExplorerProcess(dir2)

    If proc1 IsNot Nothing AndAlso proc2 IsNot Nothing Then
        Timer1.Stop()

        Dim R As Rectangle = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea
        Dim R1 As New Rectangle(R.X, R.Height - (R.Height / 3), R.Width / 2, R.Height / 4)
        Dim R2 As New Rectangle(R1.Right, R1.Y, R1.Width, R1.Height)
        Dim hWnd1 As IntPtr = proc1.MainWindowHandle
        Dim hWnd2 As IntPtr = proc2.MainWindowHandle

        'Restore the first window if its minimized.
        If IsIconic(hWnd1) Then
            ShowWindow(hWnd1, SW_SHOWNORMAL)
        End If

        'Set the size and location of the first window.
        SetWindowPos(hWnd1, IntPtr.op_Explicit(HWND_TOP), R1.X, R1.Y, R1.Width, R1.Height, 0)

        'Restore the second window if its minimized.
        If IsIconic(hWnd2) Then
            ShowWindow(hWnd2, SW_SHOWNORMAL)
        End If

        'Set the size and location of the second window.
        SetWindowPos(hWnd2, IntPtr.op_Explicit(HWND_TOP), R2.X, R2.Y, R2.Width, R2.Height, 0)
    End If
End Sub
```

---

### Solution 2

After some googling here and there, I figured out a better approach (I think)  through using the [Microsoft Internet Controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/ms970672(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) - SHDocVw component.

First, we need to add a reference to that COM component:

- In your project browser, right-click on the `References` node and select `Add Reference`.
- In the Reference Manager Select the `COM` tab.
- Find and check the `Microsoft Internet Controls` and hit OK.

We need from *solution1* the APIs and the constants only, and a new function to get the IE window:

```vb
Private Function GetIE(dir As String) As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    Return (From ie In New SHDocVw.ShellWindows
            Where New Uri(DirectCast(ie, SHDocVw.InternetExplorer).LocationURL).LocalPath.Equals(dir, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
            Select DirectCast(ie, SHDocVw.InternetExplorer)).FirstOrDefault
End Function
```

And finally, the caller:

```vb
Private Sub btnOpenExplorer_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnOpenExplorer.Click
    Dim dir1 As String = "FirstPath"
    Dim dir2 As String = "SecondPath"
    Dim ie1, ie2 As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

    If Not IO.Path.GetPathRoot(dir1).Equals(dir1, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) Then
        dir1 = dir1.TrimEnd(IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar)
    End If

    If Not IO.Path.GetPathRoot(dir2).Equals(dir2, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) Then
        dir2 = dir2.TrimEnd(IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar)
    End If

    ie1 = GetIE(dir1)
    ie2 = GetIE(dir2)

    If ie1 Is Nothing OrElse ie2 Is Nothing Then
        Process.Start(dir1)
        Process.Start(dir2)
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
    End If

    If ie1 Is Nothing Then ie1 = GetIE(dir1)
    If ie2 Is Nothing Then ie2 = GetIE(dir2)

    If ie1 IsNot Nothing AndAlso ie2 IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim hWnd1 = IntPtr.op_Explicit(ie1.HWND)
        Dim hWnd2 = IntPtr.op_Explicit(ie2.HWND)
        Dim R As Rectangle = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea
        Dim R1 As New Rectangle(R.X, R.Height - (R.Height \ 3), R.Width \ 2, R.Height \ 4)
        Dim R2 As New Rectangle(R1.Right, R1.Y, R1.Width, R1.Height)

        SetWindowPos(hWnd1, IntPtr.op_Explicit(HWND_TOP), R2.X, R2.Y, R2.Width, R2.Height, 0)
        SetWindowPos(hWnd2, IntPtr.op_Explicit(HWND_TOP), R1.X, R1.Y, R1.Width, R1.Height, 0)

        If IsIconic(hWnd1) Then
            ShowWindow(hWnd1, SW_SHOWNORMAL)
        End If

        If IsIconic(hWnd2) Then
            ShowWindow(hWnd2, SW_SHOWNORMAL)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Please note, this solution works also with drives (IE: `c:\`, `d:\` ..etc.) while the first one doesn't.

Here's a demo:

[image: IEDemo]

Comment: I just installed this code and it says ShowWindow is not declared.

Comment: I added this code to the top:                   Private Function ShowWindow(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal nCmdShow As Integer) As Boolean
    End Function                  I updated the locations to be opened and tested the code.  It opens to windows, but does not size them.  The code for If proc1 IsNot Nothing AndAlso proc2 IsNot Nothing Then never fires.  proc1 and Proc2 are always nothing.  When the windows open, theya re not set to the directories specified.

Comment: Okay, the issue was that the code was looking for the last folder in the path rather than the whole string.  It works now and I'm fine-tuning the position.  Thanks.

Comment: @Elwood472 Glad to hearing from you again mate. The issue is that I forgot to include the `ShowWindow` API. You know, an old man and sounds that Alzheimer thing has started with me. Included now.

Comment: Yeah, I found code for that and added.  I also had forgotten to set dir1 and dir2.  Other than that, the only real change I had to make was searching the process title for the whole path and not the last folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`MoveWindow()`](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.movewindow) in `user32.dll`.
The window handle can be obtained by `proc.MainWindowHandle` where `proc` is the process returned by `Process.Start()`.

Additionaly this works well for me:
https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1057230/Windows-Resize-and-Move

Comment: The MoveWindow does not work for me at all.  I first tried modifying my code with that code and it didn't work.  Then I used the examples line for line and it just didn't work.